# how to return an array in php file

Tags: php, arrays, arr

I have following array in one of my php file and i want to return that through another file

set-info.php

```
<?php
return [

    'email' => [
        'mail-to@mail.com',
        'mail-from@mail.com',
    ]
```

this is what i tried

```
public function getInfo()

{
    //read file contents from file
    $filename =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/set-info.php';
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "", $filename);
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $str = file($filename);
        $str = file_get_contents($filename);
            return $str;
    }


}
```

im getting whole contents with php tags as output. 
how to get only php array ? pls advice
    ];

Comment: The `file_get_contents` probably want's to be an `include` or `require`.

Comment: return it from a function not from a file !  . `function arraymaker (){$myarray=['apple','orange']; return $myarray;}`

Comment: `$arr = include "set-info.php";`

Comment: @Accountantم a file *can* actually return a value.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann wow!, I wasn't know that, thanks I'm looking after that

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann   thanks it works

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
public function getInfo()

{
    //read file contents from file
    $filename =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/set-info.php';
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "", $filename);
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $str = (include $filename);
        return $str;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `include` for to get that array that you can use in PHP. With `file_get_contents` you get the content of the file as string.
Change your method like this:

```
public function getInfo()
{
    $info = include 'set-info.php';        
    //Now $info will be the array from set-info.php file.
}
```

You can check more examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php